# Prove there exists a countably infinite subset $A$ of $P(\mathbb{N})$ that satisfies given conditions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that there exists a countably infinite set $A \subseteq $ $P(\mathbb{N})$ that satisfies all of the following conditions:

$i)$ $X \cap  Y = \emptyset$ for all $X, Y \in A$ such that $X \neq Y$
$ii)$ $\mathbb{N} = \bigcup A $
$iii)$ Every element in $A$ is countably infinite

For all the sets I tried, the three conditions were satisfied but $A$ was not countably infinite, so now I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $A$ was not countably infinite, condition ii) would fail.

Comment: What do you know about partitions?

Comment: A simple example is $A=\{A_0,A_1,A_2,\ldots\}$, where $A_i$ is the set of natural numbers divisible by $2^i$ but not $2^{i+1}$.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at sets made up of multiples of primes that are not divisible by the primes before.   $A_2={1,2,4,6,...}, A_3={3,9,15,21,...}$. And so on.

Comment: @UmbertoP. It could be that ii) holds and i) fails.

Comment: @UmbertoP. You could have 1 and 2 and 3 satisfied without A being countably infinite. Just take $A_1$ to be even numbers and $A_2$ to be odd numbers.

Comment: @StevenF notation fail. In your example $A$ has two elements.

Comment: @UmbertoP. That was kind of the point. A is not countably infinite yet 1-3 were satisfied, or did I misread your original statement?  Did you mean the subsets?  He really should have used $A_i$.  Still you can get 1 and 2 without three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the set
$$
A_1=\{1\}\cup\{n\in\mathbb{N}:n\;\mathrm{is\; product\; of\; two\; or \; more\; distinct \; primes}\}
$$
And for each prime number $p$, let $A_p\{p^n:n\in\mathbb{N}$. Finally, let $A$ be the collection of this sets. It is not hard to see that this $A$ is the desires partition of $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a bijection.

Define

$$A_n=\{ f(n,m) | m \in \mathbb{N} \} \,.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let each set contain integers that are the product of $k$ primes. Add the value 0 and 1 into the first set.

It is obvious that all the conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Except $0$ and $1$ are in their own classes. :-)

Comment: @asaf lol thanks.